# Avoid counting URL characters with the character Count Plugin of jQuery

Tags: jquery, url, plugins, count, character

I am using the "character Count Plugin" of jQuery:
http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas

I am trying to do like twitter does in order not to count every character of the real URL but just the few characters of the shortened one. (always the same number)

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the JQuery plugin to use f.i. a regular expression to find the url's in the string and replace that (pure for the counting) with the smaller url.

You could use a regular expression like:

```
(http(s?)\://){1}\S+)
```